# Interface that returns a class

Tags: c#, wcf, interface

I am using a WCF with a method which has to return a class. That class is defined within the Service class.  But in the IService those class names are not recognized. Since I cannot define classes within an interface how would I get these return types to be recognized within the Interface?

Here is the IService:

```
public interface IService1
{

   [OperationContract]   Custom_Class Method1(int req);

}
```

How would I get it to recognize Custom_Class?

Thanks!

Comment: Right click on `Custom_Class` and click Resolve. You are missing the namespace

Comment: You need to reference the assembly that contains `Custom_Class` and provide the namespace that it's in - either explicitly or using a `using` directive.

Comment: @Habib and/or an assembly reference.

Comment: @DStanley, definitely YES.

Comment: I qualified it and it works.  I cannot believe I forgot something so obvious.  Thanks!